# bash command to copy file contents from file1 to file2 after particular string/text in file2

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Assume file2 content is as below

```
aaa aaa aaa
bbb bbb bbb
ccc ccc ccc
```

I want to copy the contents from file1 to file2 after the line that has the string "bbb bbb bbb".

Basically, I want to search for pattern in file2 and paste the contents in the next line after that pattern.

Note : this "bbb bbb bbb" can be at any line no in file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save an updated file2, `ed` to the rescue:

```
ed -s file2 <<EOF
/^bbb bbb bbb$/r file1
w
EOF
```

Comment: I prefer the `sed` answer, obviously with the `-i` option to perform the editing into the file itself.

Comment: @PierreFrançois I can't recommend `sed -i`. It's not standardized and different sed implementations that support it act differently (One that catches a lot of people is that OS X's version has a mandatory argument to `-i`). Better to use a tool actually intended from the beginning to work on files, or one like perl whose behavior is going to be the same everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy: try:

```
sed -i '/bbb bbb bbb/r file1' file2
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available.

```
printf '%s\n' '/^bbb bbb bbb$/r file1.txt' w | ed -s file2.txt
```